# Rails 3 - Polymorphic associations only choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, build, associations, polymorphic-associations, belongs-to

I have 3 basic models: Articles, Comments, and Users. Currently the comments are nested within the articles, nonetheless all comments of an article are shown on the article show page.
My 'problem' is that a comment should belong to both a user and an article. Now, in the create action of my comments_controller it's kinda difficult to do 2 build actions at the same time. What I basically want is both a

```
    @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

and a

```
    @comment = @user.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

in the same create action of my comments_controller. Of course you can't execute both lines at the same time, if I'm not wrong. At least it would't do what I wanted.

In my comments I want to call the comment's user info to get user_name and his avatar. I could add a user_name column to my comments table and handle that with

```
    @user = current_user
    @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_name = @user.name
```

but this is kinda clumsy and get's complicated when I want to show the comment's user's avatar through the paperclip plugin.

Is the only possible way to build 2 associations for the comment (with an article and an user) using polymorphic associations with a 'commentable' interface for the user and article model? I feel like even this wouldn't be really clean logic-wise, since a user isn't really commentable but rather makes the comment. Of course, this lack of logic wouldn't be a problem for the app, but is there no other solution for the, in my opinion, rather common situation of a comment belonging to more than one model?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment model should have columns for article_id and user_id.
Try putting a hidden field in your form_for:

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:comment_id, :value => @comment.id) %>
```

Then when you call `@comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])` it should get passed along. And then you can call `@comment.user.user_name`.

Comment: In general I would agree with that approach, but user_id I think is a too sensitive information as to put it in a hidden field. Someone could easily comment as a different user by changing that id via firebug or so. I had that idea yesterday, but made the check with logging in as a user, manipulating the user_id in the hidden field with firebug and I actually was able to comment as any user I wanted. Hidden fields only should be used for attributes that noone would be interested in manipulating I think.

Comment: True. You could tackle it from the other side then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's a great idea I think. So doing a `@comment = @user.comments.build(params[:comment])` and creating the articles association though a hidden field which is no problem, cause there is no interest in manipulating it.